# CPP Metaprogramming: contains function for tuples

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I want to implement a contains function, which checks if a spezific type is contained in a tuple.

Espacially I wanted to try out the std::condition template to accomplish this work. However I get the following error when compiling:

```
In file included from /Users/harald/Desktop/Meta/main.cpp:2:
/Users/harald/Desktop/Meta/type_set.h:19:70: error: no member named 'value' in 'type_set_contains<float, type_set<int, float, double> >'
constexpr bool type_set_contains_v = type_set_contains<Type, Tuple>::value;
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/harald/Desktop/Meta/main.cpp:6:18: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'type_set_contains_v<float, type_set<int, float, double> >' requested here
    std::cout << type_set_contains_v<float, type_set<int, float, double>>;
```

My code so far is:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Types>
class type_set {};

template<typename Type, typename Tuple>
struct type_set_contains: public std::false_type{};

template<typename Type, typename Head, typename... Rest>
struct type_set_contains<Type, type_set<Head, Rest...>> :
        public std::conditional<std::is_same<Type, Head>::value, std::true_type,
                type_set_contains<Type, type_set<Rest...>>>{};

template<typename Type, typename Tuple>
constexpr bool type_set_contains_v = type_set_contains<Type, Tuple>::value;
```

I try to execute the function by calling this line:

```
type_set_contains_v<float, type_set<int, float, double>>;
```

So whats my error?

Comment: Use `std::conditional_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting from `std::conditional` rather than `std::conditional_t`. The error message `error: no member named 'value'` is correct, because `std::conditional` doesn't have a `value` member.

Also, you mention tuples, but you are using a custom `type_set` type. If you want to generically accept `std::tuple`, `type_set` or other variadic template type, you need to use a [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

```
template<typename T, typename TypeSet>
struct type_set_contains : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T, template<typename...> class TypeSet, typename Head, typename ...Ts>
struct type_set_contains<T, TypeSet<Head, Ts...>> :
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same<Head, T>::value, std::true_type, type_set_contains<T, TypeSet<Ts...>>> {};

template<typename T, typename TypeSet>
constexpr bool const type_set_contains_v = type_set_contains<T, TypeSet>::value;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc3d9ebd69132b46)